# Variable use highlighting in Intellij IDEA

Tags: netbeans, intellij-idea

One of the features I really like about Netbeans is that when you click on a variable, method, field etc. Netbeans shows you all the usages of this entity in the right hand bar as little bars of colour. Is there a way to get this behaviour in IntelliJ IDEA and if so, how do I turn it on? I haven't found anything in the settings or Google but I might be missing something!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`file>settings` or `ctrl+alt+s` (for windows) select editor from the list on the left and check `Highlight usages of element at caret` in the `Highlight on Caret Movement` section

Comment: Thanks for that, exactly what I was after. Thought it might be there somewhere - just completely missed it!

Comment: no porb! intelliJ is pretty awesome but it can definitely be difficult finding features/options at times :)

Comment: Great Q and A. But what is caret? I mean, I checked it and it works (usages are highlighted), but I do not know what is caret. Some tab which gives more info???

Comment: @askmo It's the blinking line/box/underscore (usually blinks unless set not to) that identifies where you are about to insert text on the screen.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from enabling the "automatic highlight usages" setting described above, you can also invoke "highlight usages" manually, using the shortcut **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>**.

The benefits of using the "manual" highlight usages are:

- You can highlight usages of multiple variables/methods/etc at the same time
- You can remove highlighting for an individual element selectively, by invoking **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>** again on that element
- some users find it less distracting than "automatic highlight usage" - this is subjective or course

Comment: Note that since IDEA 11.1, the automatic highlighting of usages has become the default behavior. You can of course disable it if desired.

Answer (score 2):

Above answers are correct but still to get the exact behavior like in Netbeans try to use Identyfier Highlighter plugin for Intellij Idea (available in default plugin list under window settings).

This is really strange as Idea features mentioned in previous answers would do the job if merged into the one configurable feature.